#     Dynamic Datagrid Binding in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I should do binding for datagrid dynamically at code. I wrote the code as below. When I debug this code block, it seems that it does bindings correctly, but grid comes with no columns on form.

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
dataGridObject = new DataGrid();
dataGridObject.Width = 200;
dataGridObject.Height = 200;
binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = myInstance;
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in myInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath(prop.Name);
    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
    column.Header = prop.Name;
    column.Binding = new Binding(prop.Name);
    dataGridObject.Columns.Add(column);
}

dataGridObject.ItemSource = myInstanceList;
```

Why doesn't come grid with columns, although I did necessary bindings?
Thanks for the replies in advance..

Comment: Your code should work, there is nothing wrong. Perhaps provide us with the MyClass instance. Also, have you checked your output window to make sure no binding errors are occuring?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, why Don't you set the AutoGenerateColumns property of the Datagrid to true? When this property is set to True, the code you are writing is done for you.. All you have to do is bind the List of objects to the grid and the columns will be generated by the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should have worked. Did you add your DataGrid to the visual tree. e.g.

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dataGridObject)
```